# Flutter access to GlobalKey from child

Tags: flutter, dart

I have global key with form ( `final myformKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();` ).  From come form library flutter_form_builder.
Inside form I have Stepper, and a lot of custom widgets inside stepper. How to get access from  one field to another? Simple call not working ( `widget.myformKey.currentState!.value` ) because I call it from children widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just I solve it using Provider:
`print("${Provider.of<MyProviderKey>(context, listen: false).myFormKey.currentState!.value}");`